# Direct Mapped Cache of Blocks Example

Tags: memory, cpu-cache

So i have this question in my homework assignment that i have struggling a bit with. I looked over my lecture content/notes and have been able to utilize those  to answer the questions, however, i am not 100% sure that i did everything correctly. There are two parts (part C and D) in the question that i was not able to figure out even after consulting my notes and online sources. I am not looking for a solution for those two parts by any means, but it would be greatly appreciated if i could get, at least, a nudge in the right direction in how i can go about solving it.

I know this is a rather large question, however, i hope someone could possibly check my answers and tell me if all my work and methods of looking at this problem is correct. As always, thank you for any help :)

Alright, so now that we have the formalities out of the way,

**--------------------------Here is the Question:--------------------------**

Suppose a small direct-mapped cache of blocks with 32 blocks is constructed. Each cache block stores
eight 32-bit words. The main memory—which is byte addressable1—is 16,384 bytes in size. 32-bit words are stored
word aligned in memory, i.e., at an address that is divisible by 4.

(a) How many 32-bit words can the memory store (in decimal)?

(b) How many address bits would be required to address each byte of memory?

(c) What is the range of memory addresses, in hex? That is, what are the addresses of the first and last bytes of
memory? I'll give you a hint: memory addresses are numbered starting at 0.

(d) What would be the address of the last word in memory?

(e) Using the cache mapping scheme discussed in the Chapter 5 lecture notes, how many and which address bits
would be used to form the block offset?

(f) How many and which memory address bits would be used to form the cache index?

(g) How many and which address bits would be used to form the tag field for each cache block?

(h) To which cache block (in decimal) would memory address 0x2A5C map to?

(i) What would be the block offset (in decimal) for 0x2A5C?

(j) How many other main memory words would map to the same block as 0x2A5C?

(k) When the word at 0x2A5C is moved into a cache block, what are the memory addresses (in hex) of the other
words which will also be moved into this block? Express your answer as a range, e.g., [0x0000, 0x0200].

(l) The first word of a main memory block that is mapped to a cache block will always be at an address that is
divisible by __ (in decimal)?

(m) Including the V and tag bits of each cache block, what would be the total size of the cache (in bytes)

(n) what would be the size allocated for the data bits (in bytes)?

**----------------------My answers and work-----------------------------------**

a) memory = 16384 bytes. 16384 bytes into bits = 131072 bits. 131072/32 = **4096 32-bit words**

b) 2^14 (main memory) * 2^2 (4 bits/word) = 2^16. take log(base2)(2^16) = **16 bits**

c) couldnt figure this part out (would appreciate some input (**NOT A SOLUTION**) on how i can go about looking at this problem

d)could not figure this part out either :(

e)8 words in each cache line. 8 * 4(2^2 bits/word) = 32 bits in each cache line. log(base2)(2^5) = **5 bits used for block offset**.

f) # of blocks = 2^5 = 32 blocks. log(base2)(2^5) = **5 bits for cache index**

g) tag = 16 - 5 - 5 - 2(word alignment) = **4 bits**

h) 0x2A5C

```
   0010    10100      10111          00 

   tag     index      offset  word aligned bits
```

maps to cache block index = 10100 = **0x14**

i) maps to block offset = 10111 = **0x17**

j) 4 tag bits, 5 block offset = **2^9 other main memory words**

k) it is a permutation of the block offsets. so it maps the memory addresses with the same tag and cache index bits and block offsets of **0x00 0x01 0x02 0x04 0x08 0x10 0x11 0x12 0x14 0x18 0x1C 0x1E 0x1F**

l)divisible by **4**

m) 2(V+tag+data) = 2(1+4+2^3*2^5) = 522 bits = **65.25 bytes**

n)data bits = 2^5 blocks * 2^3 words per block = 256 bits =  **32 bytes**

Answer (score 0):

Part C:
If a memory has **M** bytes, and the memory is byte addressable, the the memory addresses range from **0** to **M - 1**.

For your question, this means that memory addresses range from 0 to 16383, or in hex 0x0 to 0x3FFF.

Part D:
Words are 4 bytes long.  So given your answer to C, the last word is at:

```
(0x3FFFF - 3) -> 0x3FFC.
```

You can see that this is correct because the lowest 2 bits of the address are 0, which must be true of any 4 byte aligned address.